# Custom View Class Shows View Twice

Tags: php, html, templates

I'm creating an MVC application and I have this class (example) for the view:

```
<?php

class View {
    public function view() {
        include 'example.html';
    }
}

?>
```

But when I call that function:

```
<?php

$test = new View;

$test->view();

?>
```

"example.html" is shown twice. I can't figure out why. What is wrong?

Comment: Fiddle: https://eval.in/170789

Comment: You can remove this default behaviour by defining a blank `__construct()` function: https://eval.in/170795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$test = new View;
```

is executing the `view()` function upon instantiation. Then you are calling the function a second time:

```
$test->view();
```

In more recent versions of PHP, we use `__construct()` as the constructor, but if that's absent PHP will revert to legacy syntax and look for a method with the same name as the class.

See also: [PHP Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: Specific example in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#example-203